# Understanding the Euler operator

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

While reading [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540442286) I came across a differential equation
$$t^5\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+2t^4\frac{dy}{dt}-y=0$$
that was then rewritten in terms of the [Euler operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_operator), $\delta=t\frac{d}{dt}$, with the resulting operator being

$$\delta^2-\delta-\frac{1}{t^3}=0.$$

I'm trying to understand why does it seem as if  $$\delta^2 = t^2\frac{d^2}{dt^2} .$$ Shouldn't
$$\delta^2=\delta(\delta)=t\frac{d}{dt}\left(t\frac{d}{dt}\right)= t\frac{d}{dt}+t^2\frac{d^2}{dt^2}.$$
Also, I'm looking for a possible generalization of this for $n^{th}$ order polynomials, that is, given a differential operator
$$A(x)\frac{d^2}{dt^2}+B(x)\frac{d}{dt}+C(x)=0$$
where $A(x), B(x)$ and $C(x)$ are $n^{th}$ degree polynomials, how can it be expressed in terms of the Euler operator

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right about the definition of $\delta^2$, but  the operator should be:

$\delta^2+\delta-1/t^3$, check this with your definition and  it all cancels correctly.

Then the generalisation would be:

$\frac{A(t)}{t^2}\delta^2+(B(t)-\frac{A(t)}{t})\delta+C(t)$

Answer (score 1):

Your operator acts on sufficiently differentiable functions. Look:

Let $f$ be a sufficiently differentiable function.
The meaning of $\delta^2f$ is:
$$\delta^2f=\delta(\delta f).$$
Then:
\begin{align*}
\bigl(\delta^2f)
&=t\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(t\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)\\
&=t\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}t}+t\frac{\mathrm{d}^2f}{\mathrm{d}t^2}\right)\\
&=t\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}t}+t^2\frac{\mathrm{d}^2f}{\mathrm{d}t^2}
\end{align*}

Conclusion:
$$\delta^2=t\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}+t^2\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2}=\delta+t^2\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2}$$

Regarding the other part of your question: Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be any function.

Observe that
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2}=\frac1{t^2}\bigl(\delta^2-\delta\bigr).$$

Then:

$$A(t)\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2}+B(t)\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}+C(t)=\frac{A(t)}{t^2}\delta^2+\left(\frac{tB(t)-A(t)}{t^2}\right)\delta+C(t).$$

Answer (score 0):

No, the identity $$\delta^2=\delta(\delta)=t\frac{d}{dt}\left(t\frac{d}{dt}\right)= t\frac{d}{dt}+t^2\frac{d^2}{dt^2}.$$
not correct, it should be as you said first $\delta^2=t^2\frac{d^2}{dt^2}$. Since 
\begin{align}
\delta ^2  = \delta \left( \delta  \right) = t\frac{d}{{dt}}\left( {t\frac{d}{{dt}}} \right) = t\left\{ {\frac{d}{{dt}}\left( {t\frac{d}{{dt}}} \right)} \right\} &= t\left\{ {t\frac{{d^2 }}{{dt^2 }} + \frac{d}{{dt}}\underbrace {\left( {\frac{{dt}}{{dt}}} \right)}_{ = 1}} \right\}
\\
 &= t\left\{ {t\frac{{d^2 }}{{dt^2 }} + 0} \right\} 
\\
&= t^2 \frac{{d^2 }}{{dt^2 }}
\end{align}

Comment: gniourf_gniourf, you made the same mistake, it should be as $
\delta ^2 f = t\frac{{df}}{{dt}}\left( {t\frac{{df}}{{dt}}} \right)
$

Comment: I'm sorry but you made a mistake. Take for example $f(t)=t$. You're claiming that $\delta^2f=0$. Yet, $\delta f=f$ so $\delta^2f=f\neq0$.

Comment: for the last comment you are right, sorry!

Comment: Since $\delta$ is an operator, the only sensible definition for $\delta^2$ is $\delta\circ\delta$, hence the one I gave.

Comment: opps, i didn't mean what i wrote. not focus